# Using relations on a collection

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I have a `Collection` that holds the root category and all descendants.  In my `Category` model, I have established that there can be many posts in relation to the category.  I retrieve the category and it's descendants with this code:

```
$category = Category::findOrFail($categoryID);
$categoryAndDescendants = $category->getDescendantsAndSelf();
```

`$categoryAndDescendants` is a `Collection` object that holds `Category` models.  Is it possible to retrieve all of the posts at once?

I basically want to do something like:

```
$posts = $categoryAndDescendants->posts()->orderBy('timestamp', 'DESC');
```

Which would retrieve all of the posts for all of the categories and their descendants in that particular collection.

Thanks for the help and I apologise for the awful wording.

Comment: Wouldn't it just be a case of using Eloquent to get them for you?  If you have the models linked, then it should just be: `$posts = $category->posts();`

Answer (score 0):

I think that's not possible.

But you could write a custom Collection, and implements this function. Something like this:

```
<?php 
use Illuminate\Support\Collection;

class CategoryCollection extends Collection
{

    public function posts()
    {
        $posts = new Collection();

        foreach ($this->items as $category) {
            foreach ($category->posts() as $post) {
                $posts->add($post);
            }
        }

        return $posts;
    }
}
```

And then, you just need to set this custom collection to your Category model.

```
class Category extends Eloquent
{

    public function newCollection(array $models = array())
    {
        return new CategoryCollection($models);
    }
}
```